# Flatten BigQuery String which resembles an array

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I'm working in the BigQuery Standard SQL dialect.

I have a column that I know to be an array of JSON dictionaries.

Array length is variable from row to row.

I'd like to flatten this so I can access the JSON elements for each dictionary in the arrays.

For example, let's say I have two records.  The first has an `id` of 1, and in the JSON column, has this

```
[
    {"key1":"val1a", "key2": "val1b"},
    {"key1":"val1c", "key2": "val1d"}
]
```

The second has an `id` of 2, and in the JSON column has

```
[{"key1":"val2a", "key2":"val2b"}]
```

My goal is

```
id | key1  | key2  | offset
---------------------------
1  | val1a | val1b |   1
1  | val1c | val1d |   2
2  | val2a | val2b |   1
```

(Though I could live without the offset column)

It seems like something like this could work...

```
WITH table AS (
SELECT 1 as id,['{"key1":"val1a", "key2": "val1b"}','{"key1":"val1c", "key2": "val1d"}'] as array_column
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 as id,['{"key1":"val2a", "key2":"val2b"}'] as array_column)

SELECT id,
    json_extract_scalar(flattened_array, '$.key1') as key1,
    json_extract_scalar(flattened_array, '$.key2') as key2
FROM table t 
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(t.array_column) AS flattened_array
```

And in fact, that query returns the table I expect (minus the offset column, which is trivial to add)

The problem is that BigQuery doesn't understand that this thing is an array of JSON-like strings.  It thinks the whole thing is one big string, and I don't know how to convince it otherwise.  Editing my example to simulate this type confusion demonstrates the problem:

```
WITH table AS (
SELECT 1 as id,'[{"key1":"val1a", "key2": "val1b"},{"key1":"val1c", "key2": "val1d"}]' as array_column
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 as id,'[{"key1":"val2a", "key2":"val2b"}]' as array_column)

SELECT id,
    json_extract_scalar(flattened_array, '$.key1') as key1,
    json_extract_scalar(flattened_array, '$.key2') as key2
FROM table t 
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(t.array_column) AS flattened_array
```

Here, the validator complains because **Values referenced in UNNEST must be arrays. UNNEST contains expression of type STRING at [29:23]**

And now we're at the heart of the issue.  Is there some obvious way to get BigQuery to understand that this string is a valid array of JSON dictionaries?  Maybe some `JSON_*` function I've overlooked that will flatten the array?  Or some way to `CAST` this thing to an array?

Comment: If the array has the same structure all the time you should import the json data as an array of structs - transforming it into a format bigquery understands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use BigQuery JavaScript UDFs to parse JSON in any way you'd like:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION flatten_array(array_column STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<key1 STRING, key2 STRING>>
LANGUAGE js
AS """
  return JSON.parse(array_column)
""";

WITH table AS (
SELECT 1 as id,'[{"key1":"val1a", "key2": "val1b"},{"key1":"val1c", "key2": "val1d"}]' as array_column
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 as id,'[{"key1":"val2a", "key2":"val2b"}]' as array_column)

SELECT id,
    key1,
    key2
FROM table t 
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(flatten_array(array_column)) AS flattened_array
```

[image]

To get better native BQ JSON arrays support, [vote issue 63716683 up](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63716683), and subscribe for updates.

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and I recommend using it in case if your json is as simple as in your example

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, key1, key2
FROM table,
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(array_column, r'"key1"\s*:\s*"(.*?)"')) key1 WITH OFFSET
JOIN UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(array_column, r'"key2"\s*:\s*"(.*?)"')) key2 WITH OFFSET
USING (OFFSET)
```

you can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH table AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id,'[{"key1":"val1a", "key2": "val1b"},{"key1":"val1c", "key2": "val1d"}]' AS array_column UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id,'[{"key1":"val2a", "key2":"val2b"}]' AS array_column
)
SELECT id, key1, key2
FROM table,
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(array_column, r'"key1"\s*:\s*"(.*?)"')) key1 WITH OFFSET
JOIN UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(array_column, r'"key2"\s*:\s*"(.*?)"')) key2 WITH OFFSET
USING (OFFSET)
```

with result

```
Row id  key1    key2     
1   1   val1a   val1b    
2   1   val1c   val1d    
3   2   val2a   val2b
```

Not 100% sure, but I feel above is less expensive than UDF - which is still great option :o) especially for more generic cases with more complex json

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm going to "accept" the UDF answer due to its generality, but I do appreciate you offering an efficient solution that solves the specific case I outlined!

Comment: sure. consider voting up if not yet :o)